# Unity's "New Input System:" Cancel "PerformInteractiveRebinding" with a Mouse Click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to cancel "PerformInteractiveRebinding" with the click of the mouse?

I'm having some trouble with Unity's "new" input system. What I have works fine until I start keybinding another key, thus activating two "PerformInteractiveRebinding"s at the same time. I pressume that I can implement what I need with an input such as a mouse click, but I don't know the terminology to do it.

Here's what the code contains:

```
rebindingOperation = DMovement.action.PerformInteractiveRebinding()
    .withControlsExcluding("Mouse")
    .OnMatchWaitForAnother(0.1f)`
    .OnComplete(operation => RebindingComplete())
    .Start();
```

Thank you for your interest, and hope you have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

Discovered the terminology! Here's my updated code for anyone needing it:

```
rebindingOperation = DMovement.action.PerformInteractiveRebinding()
    .withControlsExcluding("Mouse")
    .WithCancellingThrough("/<Mouse>/leftButton/")
    .OnMatchWaitForAnother(0.1f)
    .OnCancel(operation => OnCancellation())
    .OnComplete(operation => RebindingComplete())
    .Start();
```

Comment: James: I acknowledge your note that "gents" is not intended to be gendered. It is noted. It can be removed anyway, since we prefer technical writing on Stack Overflow. (Feel free to delete my comments with a NLN flag).

Comment: (I sometimes paste this wry boilerplate: _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, hope-it-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, best regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, hopes about the good health of the reader, begging, pleading, religious and theistic wishes and blessings, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc._)